# How can I filter null or undefined values from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple class directory for my kid's class. I have a Array of students in JSON format and wrote an AJAX call for the kids' names, and parents information. But some don't have two parents or two sets of contact information? I have tried "if (studentData !== null) {
show the data} but that doesn't work.

```
 function showStudents() {

    var currentURL = window.location.origin;

    $.ajax({ url: currentURL + '/api/students', method: 'GET'})
    .then(function(studentData) {

          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("URL: " + currentURL + "/api/students");
          console.log("------------------------------------");

          // Here we then log the NYTData to console, where it will show up as an object.
          console.log(studentData);
          console.log("------------------------------------");


      for (var i = 0; i < studentData.length; i++ ) {


        var studentSection = $('<div>');
          studentSection.addClass('card');
          studentSection.attr('id', 'studentCard-' + i);
          studentSection.attr('style', 'width:25rem');
          $('#studentSection').append(studentSection);
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<div class="card-header"><h3>' + studentData[i].firstName + ' ' + studentData[i].lastName + '</h3></div>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<ul class="list-group list-group-flush>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item"><h5>Parent(s):</h5>' + studentData[i].parent1 + ' & ' + studentData[i].parent2 +' </li>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item">' +  'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact1 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email1 + '</li>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item">' + 'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact2 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email2 + '</li>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('</ul>');
          $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('</div>');  

      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's the `parent1` or `parent2` properties that might not exist, and the `contact1` or `contact2` properties that might not exist. It doesn't make sense to test if the entire response is null - just check those properties instead. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < studentData.length; i++ ) {
  var studentSection = $('<div>');
  studentSection.addClass('card');
  studentSection.attr('id', 'studentCard-' + i);
  studentSection.attr('style', 'width:25rem');
  $('#studentSection').append(studentSection);
  $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<div class="card-header"><h3>' + studentData[i].firstName + ' ' + studentData[i].lastName + '</h3></div>');
  $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<ul class="list-group list-group-flush>');

  // Start of changes
  const parentStr = [studentData[i].parent1, studentData[i].parent2].filter(Boolean).join(' & ');
  $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item"><h5>Parent(s):</h5>' + parentStr +' </li>');
  if (studentData[i].contact1) {
    $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item">' +  'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact1 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email1 + '</li>');
  }
  if (studentData[i].contact2) {
    $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('<li class="list-group-item">' + 'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact2 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email2 + '</li>');
  }
  // End of changes

  $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('</ul>');
  $('#studentCard-' + i ).append('</div>');  

}
```

Your script structure could be improved too - unless each card's `id` is particularly important, it would make more sense to use a `class` instead of unique `id`s for every single element, or perhaps to leave it off entirely if you're only using it to select the newly created container. You already have a reference to the element you just created with `studentSection`, so just reference that variable again. You can also use *method chaining*  to reduce your syntax noise:

CSS:

```
.card {
  width: 25rem;
}
```

(that will keep you from having to manually set the `width` of each created element in your JS)

JS loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < studentData.length; i++ ) {
  var studentSection = $('<div>');
  $('#studentSection').append(studentSection);
  const parentStr = [studentData[i].parent1, studentData[i].parent2].filter(Boolean).join(' & ');
  studentSection.addClass('card')
    .append('<div class="card-header"><h3>' + studentData[i].firstName + ' ' + studentData[i].lastName + '</h3></div>')
    .append('<ul class="list-group list-group-flush>')
    .append('<li class="list-group-item"><h5>Parent(s):</h5>' + parentStr +' </li>');
  if (studentData[i].contact1) {
    studentSection.append('<li class="list-group-item">' +  'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact1 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email1 + '</li>');
  }
  if (studentData[i].contact2) {
    studentSection.append('<li class="list-group-item">' + 'phone: ' + studentData[i].contact2 + '<br> email: ' + studentData[i].email2 + '</li>');
  }
  studentSection.append('</ul>');
    .append('</div>');  

}
```

(Or, even better, use template literals instead)

Comment: Great, thanks. I just finished a bootcamp and wanted to do something simple... flashforward to 6 hours later.

Comment: I guess I didn't think to add the filter to the individual lines. 
This is a really simple, static app that I wanted to do instead of copy and pasting everything into a word document.